# Call one of multiple silverlight pages from an ASPX page

Tags: c#, silverlight, gis, esri

I am new to Silverlight and this seems to be an issue every time I try to code with it.  I am adding ESRI GIS mapping to my ASP.NET application.  I am using the Silverlight control for the maps.  So, I have created my Silverlight project.  I want one XAML page to be a Map with certain features and capabilities that I can dump into a User Web Control that I can use in multiple places in my application.  This isn't hard and I have done this.

The problem is, I want to create a new XAML page in the same Silverlight project that contains different features in regards to the Mapping functionality.  But, I can't seem to figure out how to add my silverlight control to the page and not call the MainPage.xaml file but my new MapPage.xaml.

Is there something I am missing.  It seems like I should be able to do it where I call the object on the ASPX page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out:

1) In the silverlight object on your ASPX page, add the following:

```
<param name="initParams" value="map=2" />
```

2) In the silverlight project in the App.xaml.cs file under the Application_Startup function add the following:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.InitParams["map"].ToString())
    {
        case "1":
            this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
            break;
        case "2":
            this.RootVisual = new GIS_GEOLOCATE();
            break;
        default:
            this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
            break;
    }
}
```

You send an initParms object in your HTML object and then set the RootVisual to the Page you want.

Anyone see a problem with this?